# Change of basis (coordinates)

Tags: coordinate-systems

can somebody help me with this by giving me a hint how to solve these $2$ $?$:

Given

- a point $P$ with coordinates $(10,4)$ in a fixed coordinate system.
- a new coordinate system with origo in $(6,0)$ and rotated $60^{\circ}$ counterclockwise.

$1$)   Find the coordinates of $P$ in the new coordinate system.

$2$)   Write down the equation, that will transform any point $P=(x,y)$ in the fixed coordinate system to coordinates $P'=(x’,y’)$ in the new coordinate system.

This is what I have thought about: Finding the coordinates as projections and then I don't know because I don't understand what I have. Do I've $2$ coordinates$?$

Comment: The value of the x coordinate of P in the old system is 10. What is its value in the new coordinate system? And that of y?

Comment: Consider now another arbitrary point in that in the old system has coordinates (2,3). What are its x and y values in the new system?

Comment: Finally, consider an arbitrary point $(x_o,y_o)$ in the old system. Can generalize from the above examples and write the values of (x,y) in the new system in terms of $x_o,\,y_o$?

Comment: Do I have to say 10-2=x and 4-3=y ?

Comment: No. Ok, let's start with something easier. Consider the real line, from $-\infty$ to  the left to $+\infty$ to the right, and a point $P$ at $x=10$. No suppose I move the origin of coordinate and locate it where before was $6$. What's the location of $P$ now?

Comment: I don't know. We start at x=6 and in the new coordinate system it's 6

Comment: @MASL It'll be 2 as the diffrence between 10 and 6 is 4

Comment: Then what do I have to do?

Comment: Draw a line on a sheet. Partition the line in 10 equally sized intervales. That way you will end up with 11 "ticks" which mark the beginning and/or ending of the intervals. Number the ticks from 0 to 10. Take as your "origin" the left-most tick, i.e, the 0. The last tick is at "distance" 10 in units of intervals from your origin. I decide to choose my origin at your tick number 6. In my system, what value will I give to your tick number 10? Draw it! Draw it! Answer: .ruof fo eulav etanidrooc sah ti metsys ym ni suhT .nigiro ym morf slavretni ruof fo ecnatsid a ta si 01 rebmun kcit ruoY

Comment: Isn't there a fornula to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When origin located at $O=(0,0)$: $P=(x_o,y_o)$

Location of new origin: $O'=(a,b)$

Point $P$ in new system: $P=(x_o,y_o)-(a,b)=(x_o-a,y_o-b)$

Comment: However, if you don't try to solve and understand the questions I asked you before, no formula will really be helpful. You need to understand that on a paper by drawing it all!!

Comment: the new x is 4 as 10-6=4

Comment: You got it. If this helped you it would be nice if you accept and/or upvote this answer. Thanks.